# Como e qual forma melhor para calcular um valor liquido

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Esses dias me deparei com um problema que não consigo resolver e não sei muito por onde começa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho esses 4 campos no meu sistema, aonde, se o usuário infoma o desconto em porcentagem,
o sistema automaticamente mostre para o usuário, no campo Desconto em R$,  valor que fico em dinheiro,
e se o usuário informa no campo Desconto em R$, ele mostre no campo Desconto %, valor em porcentagem e vice-versa, 
sendo algo dinamico, e no final de tudo isso, mostre o Total liquido, mas isso é o de menos, so quero algo dinamico,
com os 2 campos Desconto % e Desconto R$, aonde no campo que o usuário informa ele mostre ou a porcentagem ou o desconto em dinheiro.

Se alguém me der uma luz por onde começar, para faze isso de forma dinamica, eu sei que vo ter que usar `script` mas não sei por onde começa.

Desde já, agradeço !!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bem, para aparecer automaticamente pode usar um evento html como `onkeypress` penso eu.

Agora, para calcular desconto de `%` e de `R$` você pode dar um `name` ao input e com `jQuery` quando o evento html for ativado verificar se o name corresponde a um deles, se corresponder faça uma função para fazer os cálculos de cada um.

Pelo menos, é o que eu faria.

Comment: muito obrigado, isso já me ajudo bastante, agora eu tenho uma ideia de como fazer !!!